# COLUMNS_FLAGS field values for 'Columns' collection of OLE DB Schema Collections (ADO.NET)

Tags: ms-access, oledb, provider, jet, adox

I can't find **COLUMN_FLAGS** field values' enumeration for `Columns` collection of [OLE DB Schema Collections (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc668764%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
Columns

ColumnName       DataType
...
COLUMN_FLAGS     Int64
```

for `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0` provider.

Please post **COLUMN_FLAGS** field values' enumeration here or post a link on a web page where this information is published.

Thank you.

**[UPDATE]**

Here are some sample **COLUMN_FLAGS** values for `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 provider` from real MS Access database - Northwind's `Categories` table:

```
1. CategoryId - AutoNumber        = 0x5A (90) - DataTypeEnum = adInteger (3)
   -------------------------------------------------------------------------
      DBCOLUMNFLAGS_MAYBENULL     = 0x40 
      DBCOLUMNFLAGS_ISFIXEDLENGTH = 0x10 
      DBCOLUMNFLAGS_WRITEUNKNOWN  = 0x08 
      DBCOLUMNFLAGS_MAYDEFER      = 0x02 

 2. CategoryName - Short Text     = 0x4A (74) - DataTypeEnum = adWChar (130)
   -------------------------------------------------------------------------
      DBCOLUMNFLAGS_MAYBENULL     = 0x40 
      DBCOLUMNFLAGS_WRITEUNKNOWN  = 0x08 
      DBCOLUMNFLAGS_MAYDEFER      = 0x02  

 3. Description - Long Text(Memo) = 0xEA (234) - DataTypeEnum = adWChar (130)
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------
      DBCOLUMNFLAGS_ISLONG        = 0x80
      DBCOLUMNFLAGS_MAYBENULL     = 0x40 
      DBCOLUMNFLAGS_ISNULLABLE    = 0x20
      DBCOLUMNFLAGS_WRITEUNKNOWN  = 0x08 
      DBCOLUMNFLAGS_MAYDEFER      = 0x02

 4. Picture - OLE Object          = 0xEA (234) - DataTypeEnum = adBinary (128)
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
      DBCOLUMNFLAGS_ISLONG        = 0x80
      DBCOLUMNFLAGS_MAYBENULL     = 0x40 
      DBCOLUMNFLAGS_ISNULLABLE    = 0x20
      DBCOLUMNFLAGS_WRITEUNKNOWN  = 0x08 
      DBCOLUMNFLAGS_MAYDEFER      = 0x02
```

Confusing, aren't they?

Comment: Have you seen [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3fa2bc10-8720-49db-9d5d-0fa9554b65fe/getschema-columnflags?forum=adodotnetdataproviders) in another forum? There is also a "DBCOLUMNFLAGS Enumerated Type" section on the MSDN page [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms722704%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @Gord Thompson, yes, I have seen [the thread you've referred](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3fa2bc10-8720-49db-9d5d-0fa9554b65fe/getschema-columnflags?forum=adodotnetdataproviders) as well as [this sample code](http://woldlab.caltech.edu/~diane/kde4.10/workingdir/debian/pkg-virtuoso/libsrc/Wi/oledb.sql) but I have got COLUMN_FLAGS value = 0x5A for MS Access AutoNumber field => if decoded it will be: DBCOLUMNFLAGS_MAYDEFER = 0x2, DBCOLUMNFLAGS_WRITEUNKNOWN = 0x8, DBCOLUMNFLAGS_ISFIXEDLENGTH = 0x10, DBCOLUMNFLAGS_MAYBENULL=0x40. AFAIU Jet.OleDB should have different custom enum?

Comment: Some more sample **COLUMN_FLAGS** values for `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 provider`:

**AutoNumber**: _0x5A_ - DBCOLUMNFLAGS_MAYBENULL=0x40, DBCOLUMNFLAGS_ISFIXEDLENGTH = 0x10, DBCOLUMNFLAGS_WRITEUNKNOWN = 0x8, DBCOLUMNFLAGS_MAYDEFER = 0x2; 
 
**Short Text**: _0x4A_ - DBCOLUMNFLAGS_MAYBENULL = 0x40, DBCOLUMNFLAGS_WRITEUNKNOWN = 0x8, DBCOLUMNFLAGS_MAYDEFER = 0x2;  

**Long Text(Memo) and Picture(Binary)**:  _0xEA_ - DBCOLUMNFLAGS_ISLONG = 0x80, DBCOLUMNFLAGS_MAYBENULL = 0x40, DBCOLUMNFLAGS_ISNULLABLE = 0x20, DBCOLUMNFLAGS_WRITEUNKNOWN = 0x8, DBCOLUMNFLAGS_MAYDEFER = 0x2.

Confusing, aren't they?

Comment: I am struggling to get info if a column is computed, is there any way to check that with those flags?